# How do I take an array of strings and filter them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I have an array of strings in jQuery. I have another array of keywords that I want to use to filter the string array.

My two arrays:

```
    var arr = new Array("Sally works at Taco Bell", "Tom drives a red car", "Tom is from Ohio", "Alex is from Ohio");

    var keywords = new Array("Tom", "Ohio");
```

How can I filter the `arr` array using the `keywords` array in jQuery? In this situation it would filter out "Sally works at Taco Bell" and keep the rest.

Below is the actual code I am using.

```
var keywords= [];
var interval = "";
var pointer = '';
var scroll = document.getElementById("tail_print");

$("#filter_button").click(
function(){
    var id = $("#filter_box").val(); 
    if(id == "--Text--" || id == ""){
        alert("Please enter text before searching.");
    }else{
        keywords.push(id);
        $("#keywords-row").append("<td><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" /> " + id + "</td>");
    }
}
);

$(".delete_filter").click(
function(){
   ($(this)).remove(); 
}
);

function startTail(){
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval(
function(){
    $.getJSON("ajax.php?function=tail&pointer=" + pointer + "&nocache=" + new Date(),
        function(data){
            pointer = data.pointer;
            $("#tail_print").append(data.log);
            scroll.scrollTop = scroll.scrollHeight;
        });
}, 1000);
}
```

The whole purpose of this is to allow the user to filter log results. So the user performs an action that starts `startTail()` and `$.getJSON()` retrieves a JSON object that is built by a PHP function and prints the results. Works flawlessly. Now I want to give the user the option to filter the incoming tailing items. The user clicks a filter button and jQuery takes the filter text and adds it to the `keywords` array then the `data.log` from the JSON object is filtered using the `keywords` array and then appended to the screen.

I also have a delete filter function that isn't working. Maybe someone can help me with that.

Comment: Added the Javascript tag, because this is a Javascript question (jQuery is a library for Javascript). Btw, those arrays do not seem to be Javascript arrays...

Comment: I also removed the jQuery tag since the question has nothing to do with it. Also, @bazmegakapa is right. Those are not valid JavaScript arrays. That looks like PHP arrays. In JavaScript, simply use the square brackets: `var arr = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: You're right. Sorry... the program I wrote uses a combination of jQuery, Javascript, PHP, and HTML.. just got a little mixed up.

Comment: @Xeon06 The jquery tag was fine, it indicates that the OP accepts solutions based on jQuery methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.grep( arr, $.proxy(/./.test, new RegExp(keywords.join("|"))));
```

without jQuery:

```
arr.filter(/./.test.bind(new RegExp(keywords.join("|"))));
```

Comment: @qwertymk well I have only tested in IE7 and chrome, no reason it wouldn't work in other browsers though. If you are using the second one in a legacy browser you need to shim `.filter` and `.bind` from MDN for example.

Comment: I am using this in Qt / QML to filter the content of a ComboBox depending on the text in the TextField next to it: Works like charm, just one line of code for filtering and it's really fast (no noticeable delay; got about 500 Strings to be filtered). First tried to adapt some bloaty typeahead javascript libraries but could not get it work. Your one line of code: Perfect -> Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's word for "filter" is [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
var arr = ["Sally works at Taco Bell", "Tom drives a red car", "Tom is from Ohio", "Alex is from Ohio"];
var keywords = ["Tom", "Ohio"];

var regex = new RegExp(keywords.join("|"));

result = $.grep(arr, function(s) { return s.match(regex) })
```

Comment: Best answer here in my opinion, even though it does borrow somewhat from mine ;).

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I didn't borrow anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
var filtered = [];
var re = new RegExp(keywords.join('|'));

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (re.search(arr[i])) {
        filtered.append(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since there's better answers here from a jQuery perspective, I modified my answer to a vanilla JavaScript approach, just for those who might need to do this without jQuery.

Comment: ... and I seriously have to think of regex'es top of head. nicely done. :D it'd be nice to slap it on with the `$.grep()` function though. +1

Comment: +1 very nice solution, write out the loop, and no jQuery needed :D

Comment: Might want to include a `hasOwnProperty()` if you're using `for..in` I would honestly just use a regular `for`, you are dealing with arrays not objects.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Agreed. I tend to over-use `for .. in` because it more closely resembles what I deal with more often, Python. I've changed it above.

Answer (score 1):

Top of head, and untested. As a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {

    $.foo = function(needle, haystack) {
        return $.grep(haystack, function () {
            var words = this.split(' '),
                flag = false
                ;

            for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
                flag = $.inArray(words[i], needle);
                if (flag) { break; }
            }

            return flag;                
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then you can (supposedly) run that like:

```
var bar = $.foo(keywords, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`filter][1]` function, but either way you'll need to loop through both arrays. You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check if a string is contained within another string.

```
var arr = ["Sally works at Taco Bell", "Tom drives a red car", "Tom is from Ohio", "Alex is from Ohio"];
var keywords = ["Tom", "Ohio"];
var filtered = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf(keywords[j]) > -1) {
            filtered.push(arr[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(filtered);
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hSZpa/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery awesome powers:

```
var keywords = ["Tom", "Ohio"];
$(["Sally works at Taco Bell", "Tom drives a red car", "Tom is from Ohio", "Alex is from Ohio"]).filter(function(k, v) {
    return v.match("(" + keywords.join("|") + ")");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keywords = ['Tom', 'Ohio'];
var arr = ['Sally works at Taco Bell', 'Tom drives a red car', 'Tom is from Ohio', 'Alex is from Ohio'];
var matcher = new RegExp(keywords.join('|'));
var newarr = [];
$.each(arr, function(index, elem) {
   if (elem.match(matcher)) {
      newarr.push(elem);
   }
});
console.log(newarr);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ92u/1/