# Removing unwanted words from tweets

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am creating a webpage to display the most frequently occurred word from the latest tweets in a word cloud. It is based on nodejs + html.

I am getting the tweets from my server.js file and pushing the words in text format to my html page.

My HTML code:

```
<script>
var data, twArr;
var data = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;           
data = data.toLowerCase().replace(/object Object/g, '').replace(/[\+\.,\/#!$%@\^&\*{}=:;_`~]/g,'');
data = data.replace(/[0-9]+/g, "");
var twArr = data.split(' ');

<< then I pass twArr to my cloud code>>
</script>
<body>
 <p id="data">
        {{data}}
 </p>
</body>
```

With this code, it display all junk words like urls(https:...) and words which have no meanings, also common words like to, if, is, of etc....

Any idea how I can remove all those junk and just take valid words? Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any D3 or node.js code, nor anything to create a word cloud. It doesn't looks like your question is about anything from those tags explicitly, so please don't add them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a filter list of blacklisted words. You are already getting word list for every tweets (in twArr). Just filter the words before sending them to view on the basis of your filter list. You can take help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839815/how-do-i-take-an-array-of-strings-and-filter-them) question

Comment: Could you please explain me how I can do that? I tried like this: data = data.replace(/https*/g, ""); But this just removed https and kept the remaining part of the url from tweets. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can list such multiple words are place them in one go like

1. You need to create list of words you wan to replace with For example http,if,else
2. Apply that list on your data

For example

```
var data= "Some words will be empty string now like http if but not https  else will be same.";

var mapObj = {
   http:"",
   if:"",
   else:""

};
data= data.replace(/http|if|else\b/, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with your code, it removes just that word from a word. Like for example, adding "to" into that list, removes "to" from tomorrow and just displays "morrow". I dont want to remove those from valid words. Instead just want to remove to, for example. Also, any idea how I can stop repetitive words? I want to see them once in the cloud instead of seeing it multiple times. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: @Sweet try updated code it will now remove exact match for word and will not remove to from tomorrow word

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I still see all words beginning with https.. . How can I remove all words which starts with https?